# Github User Authentication for public repositories

Tags: java, github, github-api

I have to authenticate i.e basically check whether a user is there on Github for a public/private repository. If the user is a private user i have to authenticate the user using password and username. Is there any Java API that does all these in a simple and easy way?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the most stupid thing i did.
The API to authenticate a user and download the git repository is 
GitHub API for Java (org.kohsuke.github)
It has methods to connect using password, authorization token.

```
GitHub github = GitHub.connectUsingPassword("Username","Password");
github.getRepository("Repository name");
```